# Eclipse "autosave before build" not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace, autosave

I am using Eclipse Helios on CentOS 5.6 and, (maybe) after (or perhaps due to?) downloading a plugin for Jetty, the IDE has stopped autosaving before building. The corresponding option in

```
Window --> Preferences --> Workspace --> Save automatically before build
```

is on and I have tried all possible combinations of unsetting and resetting it, as well as restarting the application.

Is there any way of "manually" overriding this option in a configuration file somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Are the files which aren't saved inside a referenced project?
If they are, there seems to be a known [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355984).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Helios this can be done by going to preferences and setting:

> Run/Debug > Launching > Save required dirty editors before launching